# How to configure hdfs and core-site.xml for nifi/lib to access hdfs in cloudera-quickstart container

Tags: apache-nifi, cloudera

My docker has 2 containers one for nifi one for quickstart, they are connected to the docker bridge and can ping each other.

I've manually put some files into quickstart hdfs:/ which i can see with hdfs dfs -ls / command.

I am trying to delete one of these files to test nifis access to hdfs, I configured core-site and hdfs-site.xml files using quickstart container ip showing under docker inspect bridge command.

nifi deleteHDFS gets timed-out when trying to reach "container-bridge-ip:8020" how do i reach to quickstart container? Is there an easier way of aproaching what i am trying to do?

I am open for suggestions.

thanks.

Comment: I had to give my local machine ip to test with docker , you should try that instead of container ip

Comment: I have tried your suggestion still gives the error;
1000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for connect. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=/<machineip>:8020]

Comment: are you able to telnet to machineip:8020 your core-site should be hdfs:/machineip:8020

Comment: I've tried hdfs:/<cloudera-bridge-ip>:8020 and it worked!